# Vagrant VirtualBox - Can I be hacked?

Tags: windows-7, security, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

Have a VirtualBox set up with Vagrant and Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.  Simply, can I be hacked?  Do I have security concerns of my virtual server being detected?

My normal OS is Windows 7, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

For lofty, general questions like this, One can only reply with lofty, general answers. My answer for a question like this is simply:

Yes.

Technically-imperfect people made the components mentioned, and technically-less-imperfect people can hack them, given the proper motivations.

That said the likelyhood is small, and someone having motivation to hack YOU is likely even smaller.

Comment: +1 from me although security by obscurity is not the best approach.